# Facebook fql location_post distance weird behaviour

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, distance

I doing the following query in the FB-FQL:

```
SELECT id, tagged_uids, type, coords FROM location_post WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '37.785834', '-122.406417') < 1000 AND app_id=364316083653078 LIMIT 0, 100
```

This returns a result with two entries.

But when I increase the distance, I get less results??? (only 1)

```
SELECT id, tagged_uids, type, coords FROM location_post WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '37.785834', '-122.406417') < 10000 AND app_id=364316083653078 LIMIT 0, 100
```

As I understand it, the first query should give me the posts within a range of 1000 meters and the second one within 10'000 meters. So I should get MORE results with the second query?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure to follow all the `paging` urls returned by the query?

Comment: I have similar problem!!
I actually get no entry when I include distance data~ I even changed distance from 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 many times but it doesn't work.
Also the location_post doesn't give me any paging url....hahahaha...

Comment: @Donn - thanks - I'll check that...

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior in a similar query i am running now. were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Not really, ashutosh. The project was on hold for a while so I haven't been working on it. It'll restart shortly, though - then I'll be able to check whether the suggestions here worked...